# How to send a notification between two NextJS apps when an event occurs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have two projects built with NextJS 13:

1. **An ecommerce website** at localhost:3001
2. **An admin dashboard for that website** at localhost:3000.

In my dashboard, I fetch all the orders from "localhost:3000/api/admin/orders" to display them in a table.
What I want to achieve is: when a new order is placed on my website, I want to receive a notification in my dashboard, like a toast saying that there's a new order.

Currently, in my website, the route for adding a new order is **"/app/api/user/order"**:

```
export const POST = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const user_id = await authenticate();
    const order = await req.json();
    const newOrder = await addOrder({ ...order, user_id });

    return new Response(JSON.stringify({ order: newOrder }), {
      status: 200,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    return new Response(JSON.stringify({ msg: error.message }), {
      status: error.status || 500,
    });
  }
};
```

I think here I should add some logic to also notify my dashboard (localhost:3000) that a new order has been added.

Also, in my dashboard app, this is my orders page where I fetch all the orders, in **/app/dashboard/orders/page.jsx:**

```
import React from "react";
import TableView from "../TableView";

async function getData() {
  const response = await fetch("http://localhost:3001/api/admin/order", {
    cache: "no-store",
  });

  if (!response.ok) {
    throw new Error("Failed to fetch data");
  }

  return response.json();
}

const page = async () => {
  const data = await getData();

  return (
    <div>
      <TableView headerTitle="Comenzi" tableData={data.orders} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default page;
```

I've looked up some methods to achieve what I want, like SSE or Websockets but I failed to get what i want.

Comment: WebSockets will do the trick when implemented correctly. You could also have a look at a simpler solution called `long polling`